# nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1 in angular 15?

Tags: nginx, angular

Iam facing with this error,

nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1

Docker File:

```
FROM artifactorycloud.ual.com/v-docker/node:16 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --configuration=development
FROM artifactorycloud.ual.com/v-docker/nginx:alpine
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the nginx conf that we created to the container
COPY ./nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is my nginx.conf file:

Updated config file
server {
listen 80;
server_name  localhost;

```
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /ui/health {
            access_log off;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
            return 200 "Healthy\n";
        }
    }
```

Original nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /ui/health {
            access_log off;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
            return 200 "Healthy\n";
        }
    }
}
```

can anybody help me on that where i am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact not your `main` `nginx.conf` file, but a configuration file for your (or one of your) websites.

The main configuration file which accepts the `worker_process` directive is under `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.

Your `http` and `events` directives will also not work under `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`.

The default nginx.conf file already has these directives inside, and worker processes is set to auto:

```
worker_processes  auto;
```

Delete http, events and worker_processes from your website config file, and tweak those settings inside your main `nginx.conf` file.

Comment: i have updated my  nginx.conf file according to your suggestion can you please check its correct or not?

Comment: You should update your question in such a way that other people see the original configuration, so that they can see what is wrong.
You should delete the directives in your default.conf file, not in your main nginx.conf file ...
And you can test your nginx configuration with `nginx -t` without having to restart/reload.

Comment: I have only 1 nginx.conf file in my project as well as not able to test nginx configuration due to some security issue in VDI

Comment: There's the main configuration file at  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, and there's the website configuration file at  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf. You're mixing these 2.

Comment: I have followed below tutorial for implmenting-https://www.arunyadav.in/blogs/post/19/create-an-angular-app-and-deploy-using-in-nginx-and-docker

Comment: I have updated docker file also previously i have used same etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf   in my docker file but in above post location is changed as well as can you tell me where file localted -default.conf file not located in my project folder

Comment: I dont know how your /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf  gets into docker container. If you didnn't add it, it's probably in the nginx image already.
First, revert your nginx.conf back to original, rebuild your image, and see if nginx works.

Comment: thanks for the update

Comment: My above error is fixed but in the logs I got new error-getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE)” can you tell me how to fix this error

Comment: That's seems like another question altogether ... if the above answer helped you, upvote and accept it, and post a new question.